# Oracle SQL - getting values out of a table where all values must be equal

Tags: sql, database, oracle

So lets say I have this table with names and scores,lets call it grades, and the score values can only be 1, 2 or 3

```
names | scores
Bob   |   3
Bob   |   3
Bob   |   3
John  |   3
John  |   1
Peter |   3
```

And I want the names of the people who got perfect score (3 in all of their scores). My problem is that each person can have different number of grades.

The expected output would be something like this like this:

```
names
Bob   
Peter
```

How do I do this in Oracle sql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this...

```
select names 
from grades 
group by names 
having count(*) * 3 = sum(scores)
```

Comment: It always helps when knowing your math. Very nice idea.

Answer (score 4):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fea6a/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE grades ( name, grade ) AS
          SELECT 'Bob',   3 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'Bob',   3 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'Bob',   3 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'John',  3 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'John',  1 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'Peter', 3 FROM DUAL
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT name
FROM   grades
GROUP BY name
HAVING MIN(grade) = 3
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fea6a/1/0)**:

```
|  NAME |
|-------|
| Peter |
|   Bob |
```

Comment: Nice. This is simpler than my answer and also has better column names than in the question :)

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

```
select g1.name
from grades g1
where g1.score = 3
group by name
having count(*) = (select count(*)
                   from grades g2
                   where g2.name = g1.name);
```

It retrieves all names that where the count of score = 3 is equal to the total count for that name.

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/29637/1